# Getting error: "variable cannot appear in a constant-expression"

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I've made a basic code in C-Free5.0, if do same as in **if** statement all showing good. but when I use a switch it gives the error: 'per' cannot appear in a Constant-expression, why its give the error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int urdu=134;
    int eng=112;
    int isl=72;
    int ps=58;
    int maths=137;
    int phy=128;
    int chem=120;
    int bio=115;

    int total=(urdu+eng+isl+ps+maths+phy+chem+bio);
    int per=(total*100)/1050;

    printf("Urdu=               %d\n", urdu);
    printf("English=            %d\n", eng);
    printf("Islmiyat=           %d\n", isl);
    printf("Pakistan Studies=   %d\n", ps);
    printf("Mathematics=        %d\n", maths);
    printf("Physics=            %d\n", phy);
    printf("Chemistery=         %d\n", chem);
    printf("Biology=            %d\n\n", bio);

    printf("Percentage:         %d\n",per);

    switch(per)
    {
        case (per>80):
        printf("A+");

        case (per>70):
        printf("A");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use switch statements that way. Just use if statements. Also, if this did work, you'd be missing a `break` statement within each case of the switch statement.

Comment: Because it is not a constant?

Comment: see above the code, i used switch statement :) not if statement

Comment: Switch statements only work with cinstant expressions. Per is a variable.  Use if Statements to cover different ranges

Comment: see my code please can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @scriptscale Multiple people have just _told_ you what's wrong. Are you listening?

Comment: i use  also this code but still same error
`case >=80:
  printf("A+");
  break;`

Comment: The C-Standard defines `case` to take a "constant expression", so the compiler complains you aren't doing so: `(per>80)` is not a "*constant* expression", as `per`  is a *variable*.

Comment: @scriptscale You can only have **one single constant value** per `case`. Full stop. No comparisons, no variables, no ranges. What you're trying to do is **not possible this way**, and you should use `if` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you, i do in IF statement and i got my ouput, i thought maybe we use the switch statement and get same answer, but i think switch statement not allow. in my code..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A switch-case is a short hand for a series of ifs checking the **equality** of a variable to a series of constants. You can't use it in the way you specified. Instead, you could just use plain old `if` statements:

```
if (per > 80) {
    printf("A+");
else if (per > 70) {
    printf("A");
}
```

Comment: "*A switch-case is a short hand for a series of ifs*" hm, hm. I'd say it's a jump-table, to expliclty ***avoid*** the need "*for a series of ifs*".

Comment: i used This previously, and i also got output, i thought maybe we use the switch statement and get same answer, but i think switch statement not allow. in my code..!

Comment: ... but perhaps I misunderstand/translate wrongly "*short hand*".